# appsync dynamodb won't return primary partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

With thanks in advance as this is probably a 101 question - I can't find an answer anywhere.

I've set up what I think is a simple example of AppSync and DynamoDB.

In DynamoDB I have a `categorys` table, with items of the form

```
{
  slug: String!,
  nm: String,
  nmTrail: String,
  ...
}
```

So - no `id` field.  `slug` is he primary partition key, not null and expected to be unique (is unique in the data I've got loaded so far).

I've set up a simplified AppSync schema in line with the above definition and 
a resolver...

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation" : "GetItem",
  "key" : {
    "slug" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.slug}" }
  }
}
```

A query such as

```
query GoGetOne {
  getCategory(slug: "Wine") {
    nm
  }
}
```

Works fine - returning the `nm` value for the correct item in `categorys` - similarly I can add any of the other properties in `categorys` to return them (e.g. nmTrail) except `slug`.

If I add `slug` (the Primary Partition Key, a non-nullable String) to the result set then I get a `DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException` of `the provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException`.

If I scan/query/filter the table in DynamoDB all is good.

Most of the AWS examples use an `id: ID!` field in the 'get one' examples and also ask for it as a returned item.

*update1 in response to KDs request*

My update mutation schema is:

```
type Mutation {
  putCategory(
    slug: String!,
    nm: String,
    nmTrail: String,
    mainCategorySlug: String,
    mainCategoryNm: String,
    parentCategorySlug: String,
    parentCategoryNm: String
  ): Category
}
```

No resolver associated with that and (obviously) therefore haven't used mutation to `put` anything yet - just trying to `get` batch uploaded data to begin with.

*/update1*

What am I missing?

Comment: Can I see your `Insert Mutation Resolver Mapping` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your API as much as I could and it works for me.

#### Category DynamoDB table

[image]

#### Schema:

```
type Query {
    getCategory(slug: String!): Category
}
type Category {
    slug: String
    nm: String
    nmTrail: String
}
```

#### Resolver on `Query.getCategory` request template:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "slug": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.slug),
    }
}
```

#### Resolver on `Query.getCategory` response template:

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

#### Query:

```
query GoGetOne {
  getCategory(slug: "Wine") {
    slug
    nm
  }
}
```

#### Results

```
{
  "data": {
    "getCategory": {
      "slug": "Wine",
      "nm": "Wine1-nm"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Tinou (and KoingDev  for looking).  You stopped me banging my head against a wall.  Following your example, I added another simple example, which worked fine - as per your post.  With my fresh pair of eyes I saw two differences on my original - (a) my type schema used a not-null (*String!*) on `slug` - tried that with and without the exclamation mark and it didn't make a difference, and significantly (b) I had left a resolver attached to slug, which presumably was trying to go do something else with the value returned from DynamoDB.  Removed that and all was well. Many thanks.